# videojs-youtube updated source not updating duration

Tags: video.js

I've managed to hook up videojs with youtube using https://github.com/eXon/videojs-youtube.  The problem I have is, after I update the source to a different youtube video, it sometimes doesn't update the duration of the player, so the duration bar doesn't work properly.

Any ideas how I can get the duration of the updated youtube video and update the duration on the player?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your code so that we can replicate and see what's wrong?

Comment: It's an angular app.  I can update the source on the page where the player is first set up, but on any subsequent pages views I try to update the source of the same player (which sits outside of ng-view), updating the source doesn't update the duration.

Comment: The player already update the duration of the video as soon as the new video is loaded using `player.src('http://youtube.com/...');`. What version of video.js and videojs-youtube are you using?